# Constantly Listen for Internet Reachability?

Tags: ios, objective-c, networking, reachability

I understand how I can test internet reachability in my app, but what i need to do is constantly listen for reachability, app wide. So if any point anywhere in the app the connection status changes, I can react.

How would I achieve something like this?

Comment: Reachability project in developer,apple.com

Comment: The code is at [Reachability Sample Project](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/samplecode/Reachability/Introduction/Intro.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/DTS40007324). The concepts are discussed in [Design for Variable Network Interface Availability](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/NetworkingInternetWeb/Conceptual/NetworkingOverview/WhyNetworkingIsHard/WhyNetworkingIsHard.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40010220-CH13-SW3).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to add an observer for reachability change notification :

Firstly import in your class: `#import "Reachability.h"`

then add observer :

```
   [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self
                                             selector:@selector(reachabilityChanged:)
                                                 name:kReachabilityChangedNotification
                                               object:nil];


-(BOOL)reachabilityChanged:(NSNotification*)note
{
    BOOL status =YES;
    NSLog(@"reachabilityChanged");

    Reachability * reach = [note object];

    if([reach isReachable])
    {
        //notificationLabel.text = @"Notification Says Reachable"
        status = YES;
        NSLog(@"NetWork is Available");
    }
    else
    {
        status = NO;
        UIAlertView *alert=[[UIAlertView alloc]initWithTitle:@"You are not connected to the internet" delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles:nil];
        [alert show];
    }
    return status;
}
```

Comment: Implicit in this answer, of course, is calling `startNotifier`.

Comment: Also don't forget to remove observer when its not needed (eg in viewWillDisappear)